# Matlab corr2 equivalent in python - performance issue

Tags: python, performance, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I ran into the same problem as presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481518/python-equivalent-of-matlab-corr2), i.e. I wanted scalar output of 2D correlation as matlab `corr2` but in python. I've solved that by writing my own algorithm, but it has performance issues.

It's based on the formula used in [matlab docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/corr2.html?refresh=true):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread

#Reading the input
a = imread(src[0],flatten=True)
b = imread(src[1],flatten=True)

#Getting shapes and prealocating the auxillairy variables
k = np.shape(a)
H=k[0]
W=k[1]
c = np.zeros((H,W))
d = np.zeros((H,W))
e = np.zeros((H,W))

#Calculating mean values
AM=np.mean(a)
BM=np.mean(b)  

#Calculating terms of the formula
for ii in range(0,H):
  for jj in range(0,W):
    c[ii,jj]=(a[ii,jj]-AM)*(b[ii,jj]-BM)
    d[ii,jj]=(a[ii,jj]-AM)**2
    e[ii,jj]=(b[ii,jj]-BM)**2

#Formula itself
r = np.sum(c)/float(np.sqrt(np.sum(d)*np.sum(e)))
```

It works, but it's terribly slow. Any ideas how to make it more elegant and faster?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `vectorized` approach should speed it up for you -

```
# Vectorized versions of c,d,e
c_vect = (a-AM)*(b-BM)
d_vect = (a-AM)**2
e_vect = (b-BM)**2

# Finally get r using those vectorized versions
r_out = np.sum(c_vect)/float(np.sqrt(np.sum(d_vect)*np.sum(e_vect)))
```

**Runtime tests and verify results**

```
In [70]: M = 100
    ...: N = 100
    ...: a = np.random.rand(M,N)
    ...: b = np.random.rand(M,N)
    ...: 
    ...: k = np.shape(a)
    ...: H=k[0]
    ...: W=k[1]
    ...: AM=np.mean(a)
    ...: BM=np.mean(b)
    ...: 

In [71]: %%timeit
    ...: c = np.zeros((H,W))
    ...: d = np.zeros((H,W))
    ...: e = np.zeros((H,W))
    ...: 
    ...: for ii in range(0,H):
    ...:   for jj in range(0,W):
    ...:     c[ii,jj]=(a[ii,jj]-AM)*(b[ii,jj]-BM)
    ...:     d[ii,jj]=(a[ii,jj]-AM)**2
    ...:     e[ii,jj]=(b[ii,jj]-BM)**2
    ...: 
    ...: r = np.sum(c)/float(np.sqrt(np.sum(d)*np.sum(e)))
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 24.7 ms per loop

In [72]: %%timeit
    ...: c_vect = (a-AM)*(b-BM)
    ...: d_vect = (a-AM)**2
    ...: e_vect = (b-BM)**2
    ...: r_out = np.sum(c_vect)/float(np.sqrt(np.sum(d_vect)*np.sum(e_vect)))
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.7 µs per loop

In [73]: np.allclose(r,r_out)
Out[73]: True
```